# Visual Studio 2015 Xamarin Forms Android Project won't display Property Pages

Tags: visual-studio-2015, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

Okay, so I am trying to work with Xamarin Forms to create a cross-platform app and am running into nothing but problems! So first I'll tell you of my set up:

Windows 10
Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise Edition

Now for the current issue (there are multiple - but one I think is the beginning of it all). I try to access the property pages to set the minimum/target sdk versions (both with Right Click on project and with Alt+Enter with project highlighted) and the same thing happens every time.

[image: The error in progress]

For a brief moment a white screen will popup with the configuration and platform dropdowns and then it all disappears as if nothing had occurred. Now, I cannot install the latest NuGet packages for Xamarin.Forms, Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 or Xamarin.Forms.Maps because of an error that says my project is targeting the wrong sdk level. I need to be able to access Property Pages to do this.

Any ideas? Below is a few of the things I've tried.:

I've tried to access the Profile that this instance is using for storage to check the targeted framework.

I tried to fix the installation (using my install media) of VS 2015 - it completed - to no avail.

Uninstalled Xamarin Forms from the specified project (hoping to reinstall it) - which did not work at all!

And to further the issue; if I edit the csproj file in Notepad++ to have the following entries:

```
<AndroidUseLatestPlatformSdk>false</AndroidUseLatestPlatformSdk>
<TargetFrameworkVersion>20</TargetFrameworkVersion>
```

instead of:

```
<AndroidUseLatestPlatformSdk>true</AndroidUseLatestPlatformSdk>
<TargetFrameworkVersion></TargetFrameworkVersion>
```

Then the project ThingFinder.Droid fails to load. If I then go in and edit to the following:

```
<AndroidUseLatestPlatformSdk>false</AndroidUseLatestPlatformSdk>
<TargetFrameworkVersion></TargetFrameworkVersion>
```

Then I can access the Property Pages but my Compile using Android version only displays:
    'Use Latest Platform()'
Minimum Android to target only shows:
    'Use Compile using SDK version'
and Target Android Version shows the same.

If I make a mistake and select 'Use Latest Platform() on the first drop down then everything I try to do in Visual Studio causes a warning pop up, 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' Which, in effect, hangs the program because the csproj file has been changed and it won't allow it to close.

I then have to edit csproj outside of VS and then reload the project to get back to square one. I am frantic here, I cannot get my mind around what is happening.

Comment: The image was an animated gif but it uploaded as a png file so the animation showing the error is lost. Sorry!

Comment: Go to Help > Xamarin > Open Logs, and see if there is any hints in there.

Comment: There where no clues in the open logs.

Comment: Also I have installed SDKs for 15 - 25 and VS is pointed at their location properly.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue just now and the answer is embarrassingly amateur and easy. I simply went into Tools>Options>Xamarin>Android Settings and I checked for the reported location of my Android SDK.

I took the address and opened the folder only to find that it was not a true sdk (though the folder structure was right it was from the AppData folder), I'm not sure how that occurred but I set the location to that of the SDK location from SDK manager (from Xamarin Studio) and all is well.

tldr: I set the proper location for my SDKs and everything works great!